# I want to remove old linux kernels

Tags: grub2, kernel, purge

But they're persistent. I've tried synaptic, dpkg --purge, and apt remove, bikeshed's purge-old-kernels, and several scripts for removal in other question-answers. All these commands think the old kernels and headers are gone.

Still have 4.4-30,43,45, and 4.8-30,43,45.

Am I just dumb? I can't figure out how to banish these old kernels

```
ls -l /boot

total 235049

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1443149 Apr  6 12:28 abi-4.10.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1242701 Oct 12  2016 abi-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1242701 Oct 19 12:34 abi-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1407739 Dec  1 11:02 abi-4.8.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   204918 Apr  6 12:28 config-4.10.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   189760 Oct 12  2016 config-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   189760 Oct 19 12:34 config-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   199485 Dec  1 11:02 config-4.8.0-30-generic
drwx------ 3 root root     1024 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Apr 19 00:43 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43128920 Apr 11 00:19 initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37850493 Oct 18  2016 initrd.img-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37852358 Oct 20 12:50 initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41316093 Dec 24 22:49 initrd.img-4.8.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3718456 Apr  6 12:28 System.map-4.10.0-19-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3869895 Oct 12  2016 System.map-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3869895 Oct 19 12:34 System.map-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4060223 Dec  1 11:02 System.map-4.8.0-30-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7567120 Apr  6 12:28 vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7569048 Apr 10 19:36 vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  7053568 Oct 12  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7055480 Oct 17  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  7054208 Oct 19 12:34 vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7056120 Oct 20 12:50 vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  7464736 Dec  1 11:02 vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7466648 Dec  6 01:23 vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic.efi.signed
```

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /boot/abi-4.4.0-45-generic` return?

Comment: _“I've tried…”_ What was the output? I think the output from `dpkg` would suffice for further diagnostics.

Comment: dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /boot/abi-4.4.0-45-generic

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`? In my machine it cleaned the old ones and left only the latest two.

Comment: I have also tried autoremove. It says 0 to remove 0 upgraded 0 new 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to keep 4.10 and remove everything else.

Make sure that you are running 4.10 and simply do

```
cd /boot
sudo rm abi-4.4* abi-4.8* config-4.4* config-4.8* initrd.img-4.4* initrd.img-4.8* System.map-4.4* System.map-4.8* vmlinuz-4.4* vmlinuz-4.8*
cd /lib/modules/
sudo rm -r 4.4.0-43-generic/ 4.4.0-45-generic/ 4.8.0-30-generic/
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Interestingly, there were no directories in /lib/modules for the old ones.